# Current to voltage converter and voltage follower

Tags: voltage, measurement, buffer

I am designing a current to voltage converter for my sensing device. followed by a voltage follower or a buffer. by varying vcc, so that i can achieve sensitivity of my circuit. do i need to have same vcc ratings for my opamps for current to voltage converter and voltage follower ic. At the moment am thinking of opa380 for TIA circuit can operate 3.5v to 5.5V single supply and OPA820 unity gain amplifier operate at 5 to 12v single supply.
Thanks

Comment: The question you are asking isn't very clear. Also, varying VCC of an op amp doesn't affect the sensitivity of its output.

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is missing infos. Please show your schematic. 
In general: You do not need to have the same vcc voltage for both opamps. But of course it is often easier to have the same vcc voltage. For your proposed amps, this could be 5.25V that satisfies both amps.